# finding corner frequency using .MEASURE in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice

I wanted to find the corner frequency of this circuit :
[image]

I run the simulation but couldn't find the frequency using `.MEAS AC f FIND frequency WHEN V(o)=-3dB` command.
I am getting this error in `SPICE Error Log` :

```
Measurement "f" FAIL'ed


Date: Wed Jan 27 11:59:28 2021
Total elapsed time: 0.067 seconds.

tnom = 27
temp = 27
method = trap
totiter = 0
traniter = 0
tranpoints = 0
accept = 0
rejected = 0
matrix size = 3
fillins = 0
solver = Normal
```

I am able to find approx corner frequency at -3dB using AC analysis using this command `.ac dec 1000 1 1Meg`

Comment: "3 dB" is meaningless. 3 dB of what? 100 kV? 13 nA? 1.1 mW? Also you'll need `mag(V(o))`, and maybe even `.opt meascplxfmt=cartesian` added. Look in the help under `LTspice > Dot Commands > .MEASURE` for an example of measuring the bandwidth of a bandpass filter and see if you can't adapt that to your case.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you for your comment. Actually, from -3dB, I meant -3dB of V(i) by assuming that `.MEASURE` works like how we perform AC analysis and taking approx value. So I changed `V(o) -> mag(Vo)` and `-3dB -> 10^(-3/20)= 0.707945`. And it worked successfully and I got frequency value that is quite close to approx value from plot

Comment: @xyz please post your result as an answer to help further readers find the solution. Comments are not the correct format for that, as they might get removed. It is perfectly fine to answer your own question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the `.MEASURE` command. As -3dB doesn't make sense so I specified the absolute value of voltage `V(o)` i.e. $$-3 = 20\log_{10}(\frac{V_o}{V_i})\\
\therefore V_o = 0.707945 \space \space[\because V_{i}=1]\\
$$

and Final command would be `.MEASURE AC f FIND frequency WHEN mag(V(o))=0.7079457843841379` which gives `f=158.778` printed in `View > Spice Error Log`

Final Circuit : [image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to find the corner frequency at -3dB of a low-pass filter :

```
.meas gmax max(mag(V(out)))
.meas AC fc FROM 0 TARG mag(V(out))=gmax/sqrt(2) FALL=1
```